# Schedule a job on linux that does not run after wakeup

Tags: cron

I want to run a particular script that essentially does power management like suspend/poweroff at specific times daily on Arch Linux.

I tried this via fcron. No issues so far.

The problem is that I don't want the job to run next day on wakeup which it will if I had suspended the machine myself.

Any way out? Would any other scheduler do it better?

Comment: Make part of your "I suspend it myself" procedure setting a flag file, e.g. `touch /var/run/myscript.flag`, and modify the power management script check for `/var/run/myscript.flag`, and Do the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Timers are what you want!

```
systemctl list-timers
```

lists the currently active timers. Arch actually has a nice article on them; you might want to scroll down to the point where they demonstrate [transient timer units](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers#Transient_.timer_units):

```
systemd-run --on-active="12h 30m" /bin/touch /tmp/foo
```

touches the file /tmp/foo after twelve and half an hour of activity.